# Update an object in an array

Tags: swift

I have the following code:

```
    struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var check: Bool
}

var anotherPerson: Person
var people: [Person] = []

anotherPerson = Person(name: "Jan", age: 55, check: true)
people.append(anotherPerson)
anotherPerson = Person(name: "Diesel", age: 9, check: false)
people.append(anotherPerson)
anotherPerson = Person(name: "King", age: 3, check: false)
people.append(anotherPerson)
```

How can I update the age of King from 3 to 4?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an item and change value in custom object array - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084406/find-an-item-and-change-value-in-custom-object-array-swift)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Okay, this works for me.

```
if let index = people.index(where: {$0.name == "King"}) {
    people[index].age = 4
}
```