# Update element in array

Tags: swift, higher-order-functions

How can we update element of an array

Method 1:-**Working code:-**

```
var numberWords = ["one", "two", "three"]
   for i in 0..<numberWords.count {
       if numberWords[i] == "two" {
           numberWords[i] = "2"
       }
   }
```

But I am looking for solution using Swift high order function

Method 2:

```
numberWords = numberWords.filter  {
       if $0 == "one" {
           $0 = "1"//cannot assign value $0 is immutable
       }
       return true
    }
```

> Error thrown : Cannot assign value $0 is immutable

Is it possible or Method 1 is only way?

Comment: Don't use `filter()`, it doesn't make sense. Use `map()` instead: `numberWords = numberWords.map({ return $0 == "two" ? "2" : $0 })`

Comment: as @Larme mentioned, you should `map` the array *not* `filter` it. The purpose of using `filter` is to determine (validate) which element should be  exist in the collection, which could lead to decrease the number of element in a collection; `map` is just a transformation of the element, which probably what are you aiming to in your case...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find an item and change value in custom object array - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084406/find-an-item-and-change-value-in-custom-object-array-swift)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do not use `filter()`, it doesn't make sense.
The point of filter is to iterate each elements and tells if you keep it (return true) or not (return false) according to your desires.

Instead, use `map()`:

```
numberWords = numberWords.map({ return $0 == "one" ? "1" : $0 })
```

I used a ternary if and explicitly write a "return" (which is not necessary since it's already done "internally" (you need to returns something)), but you can do it more explicitly keeping your previous code:

```
numberWords = numberWords.map({
    if $0 == "one" {
        return "1"
    }
    return $0 })
```

`map()` is more suited for that. You use it if you want to iterate each items and modify it if needed which is what you want to do.

Comment: Yes it's Totally fine.  How can we change `score.activeDate` . in `self.monthlyActiveDayzModel.data?.responseMap?.resultsList?.scores = self.monthlyActiveDayzModel.data?.responseMap?.resultsList?.scores?.map {
                    score in
                    score.activeDate = "newValue"
                    }` where  monthlyActiveDayzModel is struct model.

Answer (score 5):

Just as a bit of variety, you could write an in place map, which would probably be more efficient for large arrays (see also [reduce(into:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2924692-reduce)).

```
extension Array 
{
    mutating func mapInPlace(transform: (inout Element) -> Void)
    {
        for i in 0 ..< self.count
        {
            transform(&self[i])
        }
    }
}

var a = ["one", "two", "three"]
a.mapInPlace{ if $0 == "two" { $0 = "2" } }
```

Comment: Fab!!.  How can we change `score.activeDate` . in `self.monthlyActiveDayzModel.data?.responseMap?.resultsList?.scores = self.monthlyActiveDayzModel.data?.responseMap?.resultsList?.scores?.map { score in score.activeDate = "newValue" }` where `monthlyActiveDayzModel` is struct model.

Comment: @Ramesh That's a different question. I'd ask a new SO question about that.