# Convert loop into swift higher order function

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an **iOS App** in **Swift 4.2**
I am looping through **array 1** and making changes to its **one element** and adding those elements to **array 2**.

**Array:**

```
let array:[model] = []
let array2:[model] = []
```

**Model for this array is:**

```
class model: NSObject {
    var id:Int = 0
    var name:String=""
    var isChecked:Bool=false
}
```

**Function:**

```
    func customCheckboxValueChangedWithID(_ id: Int, isChecked: Bool) {
array2.removeAll()
            //TODO, use sugar syntax/higher order function for this loop:
            for element in array{
                if(element.id==id){
                    element.isChecked=isChecked
if(element.isChecked){
array2.append(element)
}
                }
            }
            reloadCollectionView()
        }
```

How to convert this into swift higher order function, like `map`, `flatMap`, etc?

Comment: As a quick side question... is there any reason that Model is a class? (And one that is an NSObject)? The standard swift approach is to start with structs. Only go to classes when you need to.

Comment: like `numbers.forEach({ if $0.id == id { $0.isChecked = isChecked } })` this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find an item and change value in custom object array - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084406/find-an-item-and-change-value-in-custom-object-array-swift)

Comment: Correct. Will remove subclassing and also make it struct

Comment: @SPatel What if I need to set this array to another array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
array.forEach { if $0.id == id { $0.isChecked.toggle() } }
```

If you just want to filter the elements and only leave the elements whose `isChecked` property set to `true`, you can use this:

```
let newArray = array.filter { $0.isChecked }
```

Comment: What if I need to set this array to another array?

Comment: After applying your changes to the array just say: `let newArray = array`. This will copy your array to `newArray`.

Comment: I don't want to manipulate my current array.  I want to filter elements having isChecked = true to another array

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an array of classes, this is very simple:

```
let array: [model] = [...]

array.first { $0.id == id }?.isChecked = isChecked
```

If you had an array of structs, you would either need to update the original array or create a whole new array:

```
var array: [model] = []

// updating element in the original array
if let index = array.index(where: { $0.id == id }) {
   array[index].isChecked = isChecked
}

// updating the whole array
array = array.map {
   guard $0.id == id else { return $0 }
   var element = $0
   element.isChecked = isChecked
   return element 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this like...

```
array.forEach {
    if $0.id == someID { $0.isChecked = isChecked }
}
```

This only works because you are using classes.

If you switch to using structs then you could have...

```
let newArray = array.map {
    if $0.if == someID {
        var theModel = $0
        theModel.isChecked = isChecked
        return theModel
    }
    return $0
}
```

Comment: What if I need to set this array to another array?

Comment: Sorry, updated. The map function returns a new array. Leaving your original array untouched. (This is where you need to be careful with classes. Using classes then even though you create a new array all the objects are just references to the same objects)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Filter**

`numbers.forEach({ if $0.id == id { $0.isChecked = isChecked } })`(Copied SPatel's comment)

Loops over a collection and returns an array that contains elements that meet a condition.

Let’s assume we need to filter even numbers only in the following array example. The traditional approach can be:

```
let numbersArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15]

// The traditional way
var evenNumArray: [Int] = []
for number in numbersArray {
  if number % 2 == 0 {
    evenNumArray.append(number)
  }
}
// evenNumArray = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14]
```

Instead, let’s use filter for the same result:

```
let numbersArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15]
// Filter
let evenArray = numbersArray.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
```

[Simple Higher Order Functions in Swift](https://medium.com/@mimicatcodes/simple-higher-order-functions-in-swift-3-0-map-filter-reduce-and-flatmap-984fa00b2532)

Answer (score 0):

how about using 'flatMap'

here is playground source

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

struct model {
    var id:Int = 0
    var name:String=""
    var isChecked:Bool=false
}

let array:[model] = [model(id: 0, name: "0", isChecked: false),
model(id: 1, name: "1", isChecked: false),
model(id: 2, name: "2", isChecked: false),
model(id: 3, name: "3", isChecked: false),
model(id: 4, name: "4", isChecked: false),
model(id: 5, name: "5", isChecked: false),
model(id: 6, name: "6", isChecked: false)
]
var array2:[model] = []


func customCheckboxValueChangedWithID(_ id: Int, isChecked: Bool) {
    array2 = array.flatMap { (ma: model) -> model? in
        var element = ma

        if element.id == id {
            element.isChecked = isChecked
            return element
        }
        return nil
    }
}


customCheckboxValueChangedWithID(1, isChecked: true)
print("array2 : \(array2)")
```

result:
array2 : [__lldb_expr_53.model(id: 1, name: "1", isChecked: true)]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class MyObj: CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: String
    var isChecked: Bool

    init(id: String = "", isChecked: Bool = false) {
        self.id = id
        self.isChecked = isChecked
    }

    var description: String {
        return "MyObj(id: \(id), isChecked: \(isChecked)"
    }
}

let array = [
    MyObj(id: "id1"),
    MyObj(id: "id1", isChecked: true),
    MyObj(id: "id2"),
    MyObj(id: "id3", isChecked: true)
]

func customCheckboxValueChanged(_ values: [MyObj], id: String, isChecked: Bool) -> [MyObj] {
    let sameIDModels: [MyObj] = values
        .filter { $0.id == id }
        .map { $0.isChecked = isChecked; return $0 }

    return sameIDModels.filter{ $0.isChecked }
}

let isChecked = true
let myID = "id1"

print(customCheckboxValueChanged(array, id: myID, isChecked: isChecked))
```