# How would I change the value of a specific element in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

Its a popular [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084406/find-an-item-and-change-value-in-custom-object-array-swift) on the topic but it did not answer my question because our query methods are different.

Let's say I have an array:

```
final class SomeClass: ObservableObject {
   @Published var myArray = ["cat","dog","mouse"]

   func changeValueFor(index: Int, to newName: String) {
     //Dont know what to put here, See below for the picture of the method I thought I could use
   }

}
```

And I want to access its properties and change it on my view:

```
struct MyView: View {
   @ObservedObject var vm: SomeClass 
   index: Int
   var body: some View { 
       Text(vm.myArray[index])

       Button("Change Name To") {vm.changeValueFor(index: index, to: "goat" }
       
   

   }
}
```

The normal way of accessing an array to display on a view is just passing in the `Int` from some provided Iterator like `ForEach` but in this case I wasn't sure how to go about it...

I thought I could use this , but apparently not

[image: Deprecated Swift Method]

Hopefully I was clear enough but let me know if I need explain my problem more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this code safely with no issue for that func:

---

```
func changeValueFor(index: Int, to newName: String) {
    
    if myArray.indices.contains(index) {
        myArray[index] = newName
    }
    else {
        print("Error! there is no such index found!")
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I have one more question about Arrays but I think I should create another question for that

Comment: I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Fast and efficient.

```
func changeValueFor(index: Int , to newName: String)   {
    if myArray.count > index,
       index > -1 {
        myArray[index] = newName
    }
    else {
        print("index out of range")
    }
}
```