# Append dictionary to array of dictionary with same new key in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

```
let resultArray = Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>()

for i in data{
    let dict = ["name": i.name,
                value: i.value]
    resultArray.append(dict)
}
```

Here i have a Array of dictionary. When i am appending any dictionary to it, some dictionary have same key and different value. What i want if the array has dictionary with same key then the new value will be added with the previous value.

let say i have the arry of dictionary with key "mango" and has value "10". If another" dictionary has key "mango" with value "20". then the new array will have dictionary like key "mango" with value "30".

example-

```
previousArray is - [["name":"mango","value": 10],["name":"apple","value": 200]]
```

after appending

```
let dict1: [String:Any] = ["name":"mango","value": 20]
```

with previousArray new resultArray will be

```
resultArray is - [["name":"mango","value": 30],["name":"apple","value": 200]]
```

Comment: If your dictionary always have the two keys name and value then why not use a struct instead?

Comment: Yes but how to handle array of struct with same key ? means if key will be same the i want to add the value. can you please help me?

Comment: You can use `firstIndex(where:)` to find the index of the object to update. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084406/find-an-item-and-change-value-in-custom-object-array-swift)