# Find an item and change value in an array of structs

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to achieve the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084406/find-an-item-and-change-value-in-custom-object-array-swift) but instead of using class, I'm using a struct. I need to change `loading` to false whenever a criteria is met:

```swift
 struct Media {
    let id: String
    let loading: Bool
    let filePath: String
 }

 struct Attachedmedia: View {
    //@State var loading: Bool
    let loading: Bool
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("demo-x5")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 100)
                .border(Color.gray.opacity(0.3), width: 1)
                .cornerRadius(8)
            
            if loading {
                ZStack {
                    Color.black.opacity(0.6).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    ProgressView()
                        .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .white))
                        
                }
                .cornerRadius(8)
            }
        }.frame(width: 100)
    }
}

// This is the main view
 struct MainView: View {
   // save gets triggered but not shown here.
   @State private var saved: Bool = false
   @State private var media: [Media] = []
   @State private var fileName: String = ""

   var body: some View {
      let threeColumnGrid = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]

      List {
        Section {
            LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid, spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(media, id: \.id) {med in
                    // I need to be able to change the loading property
                    Attachedmedia(loading: med.loading)
                }
                
              
            }
        }
      }.onChange(of: saved, perform: { saved in
            if saved {
                let id = UUID().uuidString
                let media = Media.init(id: id, loading: true, filePath: fileName)
                self.media.append(media)
                
                // Run in background
                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                    Task {
                        do {
                            
                            let response = try await doSomeThing()
                            
                            // Switch back to main thread
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                // When done, update loading to false
                                //self.media.filter({$0.id == id}).first?.loading = response.Error
                                if let row = self.media.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == id}) {
                                    self.media[row] = Media.init(id: id, loading: false, filePath: fileName)
                                }
                            }
                        
                        } catch {
                            print("Fail to upload: \(error)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
   }
 }
```

I'm uploading few images so the initial view will show a spinner. When finished uploading, I want to toggle the loading property to `false` but this bit of code not working:

```swift
[..]

// This
self.media.filter({$0.id == id}).first?.loading = response.Error

// Or this
if let row = self.media.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == id}) {
    self.media[row] = Media.init(id: id, loading: false, filePath: fileName)
}

[..]
```

An example which shows the middle image not loading:
[image]

What do I need to do to be able to change the `loading` property to false so the spinner stop shows inside `Attachedmedia`?

Comment: What doesn't work with this code: `self.media[row] = Media.init(id: id, loading: false, filePath: fileName)`? Because `Media` is a `struct` and thus a value type (also `loading` is a constant) this appears to be a correct way to update it.

Comment: So basically I need to change the struct Media to a class? I'll try that and see. Thanks

Comment: You can use class, which is a reference type and then you won't need to make a new instance of it and copy, but It seems that the code mentioned should already work correctly for `struct`. That was my question, what exactly didn't work?

Comment: Right. The struct only works when I clear the array and set it back: `self.media = []` then `self.media[row] = [..]`. That works. Weird. changing to class seems to work.